# New activity with navigation drawer - Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to make an android app with a sliding navigation drawer.

I have the navigation drawer working.

What I am having trouble with is switching activities when an item from the navigation drawer is selected. I read that I should use fragments over activities. However, I'm not quite clear on how that would work, since I've never worked with fragments before.

Currently when you select an item from the navigation drawer it does not change the layout but simply changes what is on the screen (in this case, changes the number on the screen). I would like it to go to a different layout when that happens.

Here is my code so far:

```
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView;
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            textView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                    getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        }
    }
```

Comment: extend every activity with your java class that implements navigation drawyer

Comment: Thanks for the reply! How do I go about starting a new activity from my main activity? I tried doing it with an `Intent` in the `onCreateView` function you see above. But that was not working.

Comment: @user2388643 its a fragment i see no startActivity.

Comment: @Raghunandan, I see. So, how do I go about switching to a new `layout` when someone selects an item from a drawer. Or can fragments not switch to new `layouts`? Sorry, still new to these fragments and now quite sure how they work.

Comment: show your activity code. i Activity on item click `Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityName.this,SecondActivity.class); startActivity(intent)`. But before you decide the design look at the docs first.http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html. Decide when you want activity or fragments

Answer (score 1):

Try using this way to use an activity  to your navigation Drawer

```js
private void selectItem1(final int position) {
    switch (position) {
      case 1:
        Intent a = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(a);
        break;
      case 2:
        Intent b = new Intent(this, Profesori.class);
        startActivity(b);
        break;
      default:
```

but the best way is to use Fragment in navigationDrawer
inorder to do so

> Include your Layout inside a FrameLayout

Extend your Activity as

> YourActivity extends Fragment

Do other minor neccessary changes such as using OnCreateView

inorder to use Fragment in Your NavigationDrawer in MainActivity

```js
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
  int id = item.getItemId();

  switch (id) {
    case R.id.item1:
      getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment1, new YourFragment1()).commit();
      break;

    case R.id.item2:
      getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment1, new YourFragment2()).commit();
      break;
  }
}
```